# Why is 'wget --page-requisites' extremely slow when compared to a real browser request?

Tags: linux, performance, shell, wget

My goal is to download a single webpage to be fully functional offline in the same time it takes a browser to request and show the page. But that doesn’t seem to be happening with the command I am using.

The following command downloads a page and makes it fully functional offline, but it takes approximately 35 seconds where the hard refreshed browser requests and shows the page in about 5 seconds.

Can someone please help me understand why my `wget` command is taking **so much longer** and how I can make it faster?

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --adjust-extension --execute robots=off --user-agent Mozilla --random-wait https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/essential-steps-designing-empathy/
```

**More info and attempted solutions**

- I removed `--random-wait` because I thought it might be adding time for each file request, but this did nothing.
- I thought the https protocol might slow it down with extra calls back and forth for each file so I added `--no-check-certificate`, but this did nothing.
- I read there could be an issue with IPv6 so I added `--inet4-only`, but this did nothing.
- I read the DNS could slow things down so I added `--no-dns-cache`, but this did nothing.
- I thought perhaps wget was downloading the assets sequentially one at a time so I tried to run multiple commands concurrently with between 3 and 16 threads/processes by removing `--convert-links` adding `--no-clobber` in the hopes that with multiple files would be downloaded at the same time and after all files were downloaded that I could run the command again removing `--no-clobber` and `--page-requisites` and adding `--convert-links` to make it fully functional offline, but this did nothing. I also thought that multiple threads would speed things up because it would remove the latency of the https checks by doing multiple at a time, but I didn't observe this.
- I read an article about running the command as root user in case there were any limits on a given user, but this did nothing.

Comment: It could be that website is detecting a non-human browser—aka: a bot that uses `curl` or `wget`—accessing it’s content and is purposefully slowing down requests. Perhaps trying to us `-e robots=off` as a part of your string will work. But checking [that site’s `robots.txt`](https://www.invisionapp.com/robots.txt) shows nothing that indicates robots are requested to slow down?

Comment: Or maybe adding a user agent string that makes the server believe you are a real web browser could help? Something like `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"`? All browsers have different user agent strings so maybe pick one based on the browser you are testing with? Check yours [here at this site](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Comment: @JakeGould I posted the wget command I'm using in the question; I'm using both of those flags already.

Comment: Look at your `--user-agent=` string compared to mine. I don’t believe `--user-agent Mozilla` (which is in your string) will work.